# Compare string of unknown length against string of known length

Tags: c, c-standard-library

I want to compare a null-terminated string of an unknown length (`s1`) with an unterminated string of a known length (`s2`).

`!strncmp(s1, s2, s2_len)` is close to correct, but also becomes evaluates to true if `s2` is a prefix of `s1`.

`strlen(s1) == s2_len && !strcmp(s1, s2)` is correct, but scans `s1` twice.

Obviously, manually comparing the strings also works, but loses me all the shiny optimizations the C library has picked up in the last forty years.

Is there a good way to achieve this with C library functions?

Comment: The first. But after that comparing equal you have to test for `s1[s2_len] == 0`, too.

Comment: @wildplasser that seems worth posting as an actual answer

Comment: There you go ...

Comment: Just a quickie: "... with C library functions" may be because library functions are more optimized for your machine than you could achieve with the equivalent functions written in plain C. However: you are *combining* two library functions. Would the combined functions still be faster than a simple loop with 2 test conditions (if I am counting right)?

Comment: @usr2564301, the compiler is allowed to replace several standard functions with its own versions (in a *hosted* environment), which often have additional optimizations (e.g. `strlen` for fixed strings).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if (!strncmp(s1, s2, s2_len) && s1[s2_len] == 0) {...}
```

---

If the `strncmp()` returns zero, then `s2` is a prefix of `s1`.

- if `s1[s2_len]` is NUL, then the *strings* are equal
- when not: then `strlen(s1) > s2_len`
- if the `strncmp()` returns nonzero, the second test is skipped (*short-cicuit* evaluation)

Comment: Would you not move the test for end-of-string `s1` to the front? It is an important limiting factor. (Add.) Ah, wait. The length of `s1` is still unknown at that point. Right. :)

Comment: Because s1 can be shorter than s2_len.

Comment: @usr2564301: It is not proper to access `s1[s2_len]` unless you know the string is at least that long. If `s2_len` is, say, 10, and `s1` has a null byte at `s1[3]`, then accessing `s1[4]` or later may have undefined behavior.

Answer (score 2):

If `strncmp(s1, s2, s2_len)` returns `0` you know that `s1` is at least as long as `s2`, so you can just do a check for the terminator to exclude the possibility that `s2` is a prefix of `s1`:

```
if (!strncmp(s1, s2, s2_len) && s1[s2_len] == '\0') {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: same as above. If s1[s2_len] != '\0' strncmp should not be executed

Answer (score 2):

You can use the strncmp approach and check for a NUL terminator in `s1`:

```
!strncmp(s1, s2, s2_len) && !s1[s2_len]
```